# trying to insert date to sqlite

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

I'm trying to insert a date (string) to sqlite.
the cloumn name is "date_t" (text)

there is a strange problem.

this is what I tried:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO weight_listview (weight,date_t) VALUES(" + newweight2 + "," + date + ")" ;
```

it didn't work, and it insert "0" instead of the date.
the "date" string is 16/6/2014 ( I checked by toast). date string doesn't equal to 0.

I tried another thing:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO weight_listview (weight,date_t) VALUES(" + newweight2 + ",2000)" ;
```

and it worked and insert "2000" into to database.

why can't I insert the variable data ? thanks for help

```
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
           int y= c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int d = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            public String date = d + "/" + m + "/" + y;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity3.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getLayoutInflater();
            final View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            dialog.setContentView(content);
            dialog.setTitle("הוספת מעקב משקל");



            Button dialogButton = (Button) content.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final EditText newweight  = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    newweight2 = newweight.getText().toString();

              //   int newweight2=Integer.parseInt(newweight.getText().toString());

                       Toast.makeText(Activity3.this," " + date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    SQLiteDatabase db;
                    db = openOrCreateDatabase( "weight.db" , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);

                    String sql = "INSERT INTO weight_listview (weight,date_t) VALUES(" + newweight2 + "," + date + ")" ;       
                    db.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: this is why you are supposed to use ContentValues rather than creating your insert request by concatenating strings.

Comment: Content values is a bad idea-  people need to learn SQL or they'll continue to have issues.  Still they should be using bind variables rather than concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed single quote,So to insert,use

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO weight_listview (weight,date_t) VALUES('" + newweight2 + "','" + date + "')";
```

instead of

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO weight_listview (weight,date_t) VALUES(" + newweight2 + "," + date + ")" ;
```

As @Gabe Sechan suggested, to avoid `SQL injection`  use

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO weight_listview (weight,date_t) VALUES(?,?)" ;
db.execSQL(sql, new String[] { newweight2 ,date });
```

Comment: Better yet-  use "INSERT INTO weight_listview (weight,date_t) VALUES(?,?)" and provide the parmeters in the sql call so you avoid SQL injection

Comment: thank you it works !! but why do people try to do sql injection in application?  it is not a web server they can't reveal something secret